# How can I call a parent-defined block with a new reference to this in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, hash

If I have a parent object in JS that has a block saved to a key, how can I call that in a nested object with the correct reference to 'this'.

```
var colors = {
    foo: function () {
         return this.color;
    },

    red: {  
        color: 'red',
        myColor: function () {
            return foo();
        }
    },

    blue: {
        color: 'blue',
        myColor: function () {
            return foo();
        }
    }
};
```

So that what I call this

```
colors.blue.myColor();
```

The output would be

```
"blue"
```

The exact context i'm using this idea is

```
    var accounts = {
      checking: {
        balance: 0,
        deposit: function (amount) {
            if (amount > 0) {
                this.balance += amount;
            }
        },
        withdraw: function (amount) {
            var tA = accounts.totalAmount();
            if (amount > 0 && amount <= this.balance) {
                this.balance -= amount;
            } else if (tA >= amount) {
                accounts.savings.withdraw(amount - this.balance);
                this.balance = 0;
            }
        }
      },

      savings: {
        balance: 0,
        deposit: function (amount) {
            if (amount > 0) {
                this.balance += amount;
            }
        },
        withdraw: function (amount) {
            var tA = accounts.totalAmount();
            if (amount > 0 && amount <= this.balance) {
                this.balance -= amount;
            } else if (tA > amount) {
                accounts.checking.withdraw(amount - this.balance);
                this.balance = 0;
            }
        }
      },

      totalAmount: function() {
        return accounts.savings.balance + accounts.checking.balance
      }
    };
```

where I would like to pull the deposit function outside of savings and checking and instead call the block.

Comment: There is no way to get a parent object reference in javascript unless you store one yourself (which can't be done in a static declaration - it has to be done with code).  You also can't access parent properties without someone else giving you a parent reference.

Comment: Seems like you're better off defining a class `Color`, which has a field `color` and function `myColor()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 How would I avoid duplication of the function, if I wanted to call it outside of the object, say, on a click event?

Would I parse this into the foo() function, and then use that? 

Sorry, I'm a little lost on what I should be reading up on what to do.

Comment: @NickTho - We'd have to see what you're really trying to accomplish with your code, but my guess is that you need a different data structure that is easier to  use.

Comment: @musical_coder I'm using this idea in a slightly different context where each child object will have a different function, not just myColor(), but each of those functions would have to at some point call foo().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried passing the value to the foo()?

```
var colors = {
    foo: function (t) {
         return t.color;
    },

    red: {  
        color: 'red',
        myColor: function () {
            return colors.foo(this);
        }
    },

    blue: {
        color: 'blue',
        myColor: function () {
            return colors.foo(this);
        }
    }
};

colors.blue.myColor();
```

Comment: Yes! Thankyou. It seems so silly to me now that I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `myColor`, it will look for a function object named `foo`, but it will not be able to find one, in its scope. So, it will fail.

What you can actually do is, define a private `foo` function with the help of an IIFE, and make `myColor` a reference to `foo`, like this

```
var colors = (function() {

    function foo() {
        return this.color;
    }

    return {
        red: {
            color: 'red',
            myColor: foo
        },

        blue: {
            color: 'blue',
            myColor: foo
        }
    }
})();

console.log(colors.blue.myColor());
# blue
console.log(colors.red.myColor());
# red
```

Comment: Thankyou! I'll now structure these objects like this from now on, so that its scope is properly defined.